# Checking success, error and complete statuses in ajax script

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have below script in asp.net mvc:

```
       $.ajax({
           url: "/MyController/MyAction/",
           type: 'POST',
           data: $("#Myform").serialize(),
           success: function () {
               // Do something
           },
           error: function () {
               // Do something
           },
           complete: function () {
               // Do something                 
           },
           beforeSend: function () {
               // Do someting
           }
       });
```

This script calls to an action in the controller. The controller performs some actions and sometimes things go ok or not. If things went ok, I want success and complete options in the script get executed.No problem until here, but if in the controller there is an error or something I want to tell the script: "hey, there is an error!" and then the error option in the script to be executed. How to do this? Do I have to return something from the controller to the script to indicate an error has been generated in order to error option in the script gets executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) to 4xx or 5xx in the controller.

That will make you end up in the error callback.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the AJAX request goes an error is an transfer/network error getting the page.

If you want to return an error either return it in the data then parse that and execute the error function inside the success part if you detect an error. Or as, Johan says, return an HTTP error code from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Use try catch in your action like,

```
public ActionResult Sample()
{

try
{
return Json(new{status="success"},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
return Json(new{status="failed"},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
}
```

In your ajax call success check with condition like,

```
if(data.status=='success')
{
alert('All Happies');
}
else
{
alert('error came');
}
```

Hope this helps.